# Move Extensions without Annoying Users

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webstore

Ok,

So about a year ago (I think) google went through a transition where they made Google Apps accounts "real" so we could use them in places like the Chrome Web Store.  Unfortunately, prior to that happening I had written some extensions that were under the now conflicting account.  So, now what I've got is a two accounts where the old extensions are under this conflicting account and anything past that date is under the new account.

So, it is time to upgrade some of these (old extensions), what I'd like to do is move the extensions under the apps account in a way that doesn't cause problems for the users.  Does anyone know a way?  It seems like the only option is just to place the extensions under the new account and delete them under the old account, but then I think all of the users would have to know to install the new one.

Thoughts?  Has someone gone through this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** As @artur-nowak pointed out in the comments it is now possible to transfer extensions between accounts using [this form](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer).

---

If only your extensions were hosted outside Chrome Web Store (CWS) it would be possible to solve this by modifying `update_url` in `manifest.json` (so that extensions will start to download updates from another source). But they are not, and CWS doesn't allow you to modify the `update_url` param. Because of that, I believe you have two options left:

- wait for google to add 'change ownership' function in CWS
- or add your extensions to CWS again as a desired user and update the old ones to display a popup/notification "please update" with a link to the new version. Users should be more eager to update if you include some new features to attract them. Also, it will be less annoying from them if config will be preserved. To achieve this, export settings to bookmarks panel (it will be easy to access them) and import them in the new version of extension when it's installed.

Comment: 2014 update: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer